# How can an inherited controller add to parent's before_action conditions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

```
class ParentController < ApplicationController
  before_action admin_user, only: [:create, :update]
end

class ChildController < ParentController
  before_action admin_user #Also want to add :tweet

  def tweet
  end
end
```

In the ChildController we could use

```
before_action admin_user, only: [:create, :update, :tweet]
```

but then if I change anything in the parent's before_action, it won't get updated in the child.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could call the method inside of a block inside ChildController instead of passing it by name. That would look like this:

```
class ParentController < ApplicationController
  before_action admin_user, only: [:create, :update]
end

class ChildController < ParentController
  before_action(only: [:tweet]) { admin_user }

  def tweet
  end
end
```

Answer (score 7):

Unfortunately, the way [`ActiveSupport::Callbacks`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activesupport/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb) is implemented does not allow an additional action to be easily added to the configuration of the before filter. You could do this though:

```
class ParentController < ApplicationController
  AdminActions = [:create, :update]
  before_action :admin_user, only: AdminActions
end

class ChildController < ParentController
  before_action :admin_user, only: superclass::AdminActions + [:tweet]
end
```

Comment: Clever! I'll take it for now.

Comment: Nice! I'll have one too!